# An Expansion Problem (Algebra)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the expansion of $(1+x)^n$, if the Coeff of $T_r$ : Coeff of $T_{r+1}$ : Coeff of $T_{r+2}$ = a:b:c, prove that $r = \frac{a(b+c)}{b^2-ac}$, where $b^2$ does not equal ac, and a, b, c $\in Z^+$

Comment: What are the ratio of the terms? It is not given.

Comment: @Rohan sorry, edited

Comment: You don't say what you have attempted. Have you tried replacing a,b,c by binomial coefficients ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, yes, but I am seriously not sure how to approach the problem...

Comment: $\binom{n}{r+1}=a\binom{n}{r} \ \iff \ \frac{n!}{(r+1)!(n-r-1)!}=a\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ with $a=\frac{n-r}{r+1}$

Comment: Since you are new and haven't done so, please up vote answers if you think they are good, even answers not on your questions, and mark answers with a checkmark of they have answered your question.  These buttons are on the upper left of each answer.

Answer (score 2):

We know that the coefficient of the $r$th term in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ is : $\binom{n}{r-1}$. Similarly the coefficients of the $(r+1)$th and $(r+2)$th term are respectively: $\binom{n}{r} \text{and} \binom{n}{r+1}$.

Thus, we have, $$\frac{T_{r+1}}{T_r} =\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{\binom{n}{r-1}} = \frac{n-r+1}{r} =\frac{b}{a} ...(1)$$ $$\frac{T_{r+2}}{T_{r+1}} =\frac{\binom{n}{r+1}}{\binom{n}{r}} = \frac{n-r}{r+1} = \frac{c}{b} ...(2)$$ Then we have from $(1)$ and $(2)$, $$n = \frac{b}{a}r-(-r+1) = \frac{c}{b}(r+1) +r$$ Solving for $r$, we thus get,$$\boxed{r =\frac{a(b+c)}{b^2-ac}}$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: Well written solution [+1]. I wonder if there is a proof that does not explicitly use properties of binomial coefficients.